# python マルチスレッドで共有変数の更新方法

Tags: python

python でマルチスレッドを勉強中です

以下のようなクリティカルセッションでカウンタを増やすだけのプログラムを書いたのですが
LOCKを入れた途端デッドロックしてるのか何も表示されなくなります

```
import concurrent.futures
import time
import threading
LOCK = threading.Lock()

count = 0

def func1():
  with LOCK:   # この行がなければ動く
    count += 1
  print(count)


if __name__ == "__main__":
  executor = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=2)
  while True:
    executor.submit(func1)
    time.sleep(1)
```

```
LOCK.acquire(blocking=True)
  count += 1
  LOCK.release()
```

と書いても同じです
 count += 1 
は絶対脱出するはずなのでデッドロックは起きようがないと思うんですが
C の pthread_mutex_lock のようなものではないんでしょうか

Comment: 後ろ2つの記事あたりが参考になるかも [■スレッドのロック](https://qiita.com/__init__/items/74b36eba31ccbc0364ed#%E3%82%B9%E3%83%AC%E3%83%83%E3%83%89%E3%81%AE%E3%83%AD%E3%83%83%E3%82%AF), [class threading.Lock](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/threading.html#threading.Lock), [スレッド間排他制御のwithステートメント考察](https://qiita.com/sitar-harmonics/items/a5295bf0b032d7ffcd01), [with構文の中でスレッドをロックしたい](https://qiita.com/GRGSIBERIA/items/5e5d6d7afb40a7fc5c34)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

グローバル変数宣言をしていないため、実行時に`UnboundLocalError`が起こっていることが原因です。

次のように修正してみてください。

```
def func1():
    global count
    with LOCK:
        count += 1
    print(count)
```

ランタイムエラーを見るには`Future`の`result()`メソッドや`exeception()`メソッドを使うと良いようです。

```
executor.submit(func1).add_done_callback(lambda f: print(f.exception()))
```

Comment: スレッド内でおきたエラーはデフォルトでは表示されないのですね。ありがとうございました